# How to use not exists with insert?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I'm trying to frame the below query but it always gives me the error "SQL command not properly ended". How do i use it??

```
  INSERT INTO PROGRAM_KPI (AMSPROGRAMID,MASTER_KPI_ID,LASTUPDATEDBYDATALOAD) 
  (SELECT 'PRG-026',MASTER_KPI_ID,to_char(sysdate,'dd-mon-yy hh.mi.ss') from kpi_master)
   WHERE NOT EXISTS(select * from insight_master
          where amsprogramid = V_PROGRAMID
          and inamsscope = 1
          and tickettype = 'INCIDENT'
          and TICKETSUBMITDATE is not null);
```

Comment: Which part of the statement do you think the WHERE clause belongs to?

Comment: Remove the parentheses around the `select` part.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this..(Removing the brackets and formating the code)

```
INSERT INTO program_kpi
                    (amsprogramid, master_kpi_id, lastupdatedbydataload)
           SELECT 'PRG-026', master_kpi_id, TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'dd-mon-yy hh.mi.ss')
           FROM   kpi_master
           WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
                     SELECT *
                     FROM   insight_master
                     WHERE  amsprogramid = v_programid AND inamsscope = 1
                            AND tickettype = 'INCIDENT'
                            AND ticketsubmitdate IS NOT NULL);
```

But What is the relation between table program_kpi and insight_master ?

There seems to be no join between the inner and outer subquery.

Comment: The original parentheses were unbalanced.  Removing them wasn't strictly necessary, adding another `)` would have also worked.  It's valid to use parentheses in front of `SELECT` in almost any context.  For example, `(select * from dual);` is a valid query.